# Is there any way to enable code completion for Perl in vim?

Tags: perl, vim, vi

Surprisingly as you get good at vim, you can code even faster than standard IDEs such as Eclipse. But one thing I really miss is code completion, especially for long variable names and functions.

Is there any way to enable code completion for Perl in vim?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> (Get Previous Match) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> (Get Next Match) are kind of pseudo code completion.  They basically search the file (Backwards for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>, Forwards for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>) you are editing (and any open buffers, and if you are using TAGS anything in your TAG file) for words that start with what you are typing and add a drop down list.  It works surprisingly well for variables and function names, even if it isn't intellisense.  Generally I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> as the variable or function I am looking for is usually behind in the code.  Also if you keep the same copy of Vim open, it will search the files you have previously opened.

Comment: This was working great for me, but I've recently switched to a new development environment. Now instead of searching only my open buffers it seems to search my entire source tree which takes quite a while - and only does this for Perl. How can I see if this new environment is using TAGS? I tried `:tag` and got `E73: tag stack empty`. Is there something other than tags that might have been enabled? Also the new environment has a slightly newer version of vim. I'd like to have it ONLY search the open buffers.

Answer (score 9):

Vim 7 supports omni completion.

For example, I have this in my vimrc

```
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
```

and then, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> in Insert mode, I get a dropdown list of autocomplete possibilities.

Here's an omnicfunc [for perl](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1924).  No idea how well it works though.

Answer (score 8):

Well, Vim's generic completion mechanism is surprisingly good, just using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> in insert mode. Also, line completion is very handy, using C-x C-l.

Also check out this [vim script for perl](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=556).

Answer (score 5):

The standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> works even better if you add the following to your `~/.vim/ftplugin/perl.vim` file:

```
set iskeyword+=:
```

Then it will autocomplete module names, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The .vimrc clip in one of the other answers is slightly wrong. To turn your tab key into an auto-complete key, use this code:

```
inoremap <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<cr>

function! InsertTabWrapper()
    let col = col('.') - 1
    if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
        return "\<tab>"
    else
        return "\<c-p>"
    endif
endfunction
```

You can find this, and tons of other vim tricks [in this thread at Perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=540167)--which links to even more threads with lots more customizations.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

This is explained in the Perl Hacks book, along with how to do Package completion. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the SuperTab plugin:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643
It let's you do completion (either the OmniCompletion or the regular completion) using tab and shift-tab instead of ^N and ^P.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/c9s/perlomni.vim