# How to tame Vim keyword (not omni) completion for Perl files?

Tags: perl, vim, omnicomplete

[Update 06/2013: As user doubleDown observed, I have the terminology wrong: The handy `C-p` and `C-n` keystrokes are *not* **omni** completion (omnicompletion), *but* **keyword** completion. I think the Vim terminology is somewhat unfortunate here: *omni* is Latin for *every*, whereas *keyword* seems to be a more restricted selection. The way `C-p` and `C-n` work by default is to complete every word of prose, not just keywords. Which made me think that they must be *omni* completion, not just *keyword* completion.]

Well ... :-) ... just typing in the title of my question, a [highly effective answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915152/do-not-include-required-files-into-vim-omnicompletion/935172#935172) turned up in the catalogue of questions with similiar titles. (Which just goes to show how good this website is!) I'm going to ask the question anyway - maybe someone's got an even more fulfilling answer in store ... So here goes:

[Vim keyword <strike>omni</strike>completion (by default bound to `C-p` and `C-n` in edit mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54104/269126) is a poor man's Intellisense, that in my experience is almost as good. It searches the buffers for matching strings.

However, some filetype scripts go over the top by having keyword <strike>omni</strike>completion perform a recursive search of included files. (**Update:** Searching included files is actually the default, as can be seen by `:help 'complete'` as of Vim 7.3; it's just that with some filetypes, lots of stuff gets included, which results in slowness, possibly aggravated by suboptimal algorithms.) So for a Perl script, it'll start searching the list of modules. Recursively. That can quickly degenerate into some serious scanning, you know, disk I/O and all that ugly stuff.

As a result, I rather refrain from using the feature, because I lose the time and convenience I'm gaining by having to interrupt the search using `C-c`, which leaves some random string in the output that I then have to delete.

So the best solution so far is simply to disable use of included files in default completion by saying:

```
:set complete-=i    # remedy
:help 'complete'    # documentation
```

Anything to add to that?

Comment: With C++ and Boost, even running everything from tmpfs is slow with complete+=i... I always run complete-=i

Comment: Pretty sure the thing you are talking about is keyword completion, which is different from omnicompletion (used via `C-X` `C-O`). I haven't fully comprehend omnicompletion yet, but so far the default one which parses syntax files, is proving quite unsatisfactory I must say.

Comment: @doubleDown: What I'm talking about is omnicompletion (which is fine by itself) triggering a recursive search of included files (which may slow you down because of disk I/O when too many files are pulled in, as may happen with Perl or C++ files, among others). Solution to that problem as in my question and answer.

Comment: ok let me explain: `C-p` and `C-n` performs keyword completion (see `:h compl-generic`), whereas `C-x` then `C-o` performs omnicompletion (see `:h compl-omni). You're not using omnicompletion at all.

Comment: @doubleDown: You're right - I've had the terminology wrong for years. I updated my question to highlight the error and the difference. Thanks.

Comment: To be fair, they look very similar except for how they generate the list of possible matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be a little more surgical, you can use:

```
autocmd FileType perl set complete-=i
```

so that you are just impacting the behaviour for perl code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use perlomni writen by c9s.

https://github.com/c9s/perlomni.vim

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2852

You can see video how to use.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZ7871WcIv0

for easy way, to complete method, type something and "->", then .

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->new;

$dt->ye # type <c-x><c-o>, you'll get $dt->year
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't appear to work on my installation: Vim 7.3.3 on Cygwin, `~/.vim/bin in PATH, filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`. No errors during Vim startup, but on attempting C-x C-o as per the README, I'm getting: `Omni-Ergänzung (^O^N^P) Muster nicht gefunden`, which should translate to `omni completion: pattern not found`. Thanks anyway, this might evolve into something very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's really nothing more to this issue than what I already stated in my question:

```
:set complete-=i    # remedy
:help 'complete'    # documentation
```

Just to add some Vim news to this otherwise redundant answer, I've recently spiced up my Vim configuration (mostly using GVim on Windows) with a nice typeface and some great plugins:

- [Consolas font (or Inconsolata, or Anonymous Pro, or Droid)](http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts/)
- [CtrlP file searcher](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) - (You might want to tweak it to do exact matching, which is what I did, just comment out some lines of code which make the matching "fuzzy", which is not what I want it to be.)
- [Powerline, a fancy status bar](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline)
- `colorscheme evening` " standard, I think
- `set relativenumber`  " standard, but I just didn't know about it :)

[image: GVim on Win7 with all of the above features]